# Get the users email based on their username

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Is there any built in way to get a users email address based on their username in ASP.NET 4.0? Or do I have to query the necessery tables?

I'm using this to get the logged in user:

```
string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

Is there similar functionality to get the currently logged in users email from the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Membership.GetUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx) method, which takes the username.  This returns a MembershipUser object, which has an [Email](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.email.aspx) property.  So, something like this:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(username);
var email = null;

if (user != null)
{
    email = user.Email;
}
```

System.Web.Security moved to the System.Web.ApplicationServices assembly in .NET 4.0 Framework, so you manually need to add a reference to that assembly to access Membership.

Comment: If you need an email of current user you don't need to pass username, just call Membership.GetUser()